# Add categorys to custom post type not working

Tags: php

```
register_post_type("butik", [
    "labels" => [
        "name" => "Butik",
        "singular_name" => "Butik"
    ],
    "show_ui" => true,
    'public' => true,
    'rewrite' => [
        'slug' => 'butik'
    ],
    "supports" => [
        "title",
        "editor",
        "thumbnail"
    ],
    'taxonomies' => array('category')
]);
```

That's my code for registering the post type and trying to add the taxonomies, but it still aint showing.

Any clues?

Thankyou for your effort!

Comment: what's not showing? the taxonomy meta box, or the posts on the term archive pages?

Comment: Your code looks ok. Just one note, you should add that code inside a function and hook that function to `init`. Pro tip, if you use new array syntax, stick with that, don't mix the new and old array syntax. `'taxonomies' => array('category')` should be`'taxonomies' => ['category']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the way to register a Taxonomy.Please find the code below to register a Taxonomy for a custom post type :-

```
$args = array(
    "label"                         => "Butik Categories",
    "singular_label"                => "Butik Category",
    'public'                        => true,
    'hierarchical'                  => true,
    'show_ui'                       => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'             => false,
    'args'                          => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
    'rewrite'                       => false,
    'query_var'                     => true
);

register_taxonomy( 'butik-category', 'butik', $args );
```

Hope that solves the problem.You can also use plugins like Custom Post Type UI to easily create Custom Post Type.Here is the link :- https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/
Hope that helps :)

Comment: OP's code is PHP 5.4 short array syntax.

Comment: To add, the OP is looking to register the default taxonomy `category` to his post type :-)

Comment: :) OP's code wont work prior to 5.4 .

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    "label"                         => "Butik Categories",
    "singular_label"                => "Butik Category",
    'public'                        => true,
    'hierarchical'                  => true,
    'show_ui'                       => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'             => false,
    'args'                          => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
    'rewrite'                       => false,
    'query_var'                     => true
);

register_taxonomy( 'butik-category', 'butik', $args );
```

That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.